# Está tudo bem em sempre chamar uma função ou devo armazenar o resultado?

Tags: c++, funções, variáveis, desempenho, lógica

É uma boa prática armazenar o valor retornado de uma função como `QSqlRecord rec = q.record()` em vez de  `q.value(q.record().indexOf("id")).toString()`?

Posso estar enganado, mas chamar uma função constantemente poderia de certa forma deixar a execução do código mais pesada ou isso não faz nenhuma diferença?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Toda vez que vai usar um valor mais de uma vez o mais correto deveria ser armazenar em uma [variável](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/181332/101), é para isso que variável serve.

Algumas funções não determinísticas e/ou com efeitos colaterais podem inclusive dar resultados diferentes em cada chamada ou alterar algum dado em outro lugar por causa da chamada, então a chamada seguida pode ser bem ruim, além do que em certos casos pode pesar sim, embora isso dependa de muitos fatores e da tecnologia usada. Em casos que envolva IO na função pode dar uma diferença enorme de performance, além de poder trazer valor diferente em cada chamada.

Porém, quando o valor será usado apenas uma vez o armazenamento do valor em uma variável não faz muito sentido. Até faz um pouco como forma de documentar se você usar uma variável com nome muito significativo, mas geralmente isso é necessário quando o código já não está muito bom, quando ele é fácil de entender não precisa, basta chamar a função e já usar o valor onde precisa.

No exemplo citado, olhando apenas ao que foi mostrado e sem ver o contexto geral (tudo depende de contexto para tomar decisão, não é receita de bolo mágica que serve para tudo como algumas pessoas acham), dá na mesma fazer de uma forma ou outra, porém acho mais pertinente a segunda que não armazena o valor. Inclusive é o que fez em seguida porque usou 3 (quem sabe 4) valores sem armazenar em variável, se não faz em um lugar por que faria em outro?

Há casos que criar uma variável pode deixar o código ligeiramente mais lento, mas depende de muitas circunstâncias para ficar pensando nisso, e quase sempre não tem muito o que fazer nesses casos, a variável se torna quase impossível de não existir. Isso faz sentido em caso de extrema otimização, aí a pessoa terá que avaliar o código Assembly gerado, entender profundamente todo funcionamento de tudo internamente, é bem complicado e quase sempre não vale o esforço.

Boa prática é para quem não sabe programar e quer que alguém lhe diga o que fazer, bons programadores aprendem e entendem todos os mecanismos, como funcionam, a relação entre tudo e toma decisões de acordo com contexto.